# MoralisProvider not Working(TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, environment-variables, typeerror, moralis

moralisprovider is not working in Next.js

```
 import { MoralisProvider } from 'react-moralis' 
    function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) 
     {   return (
        <MoralisProvider
        serverUrl={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MORALIS_SERVER}
        appId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MORALIS_APP_ID}
        >
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </MoralisProvider>
        ) } 
    export default MyApp
```

It says that
[typererror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hQIk.png)
why it is not working?

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
```

Comment: refer this forum..  https://forum.moralis.io/t/solved-typeerror-right-hand-side-of-instanceof-is-not-callable/18621/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downgrading your moralis SDKs version to moralis@1.8.0 react-moralis@1.4.0

Reference: https://forum.moralis.io/t/solved-typeerror-right-hand-side-of-instanceof-is-not-callable/18621/10

Answer (score -1):

That error is coming from web3uikit package, you can remove it first and try again..

When I removed, it worked..

if still error, you can downgrading to moralis@1.8.0 react-moralis@1.4.0 fixed it for my next.js react project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).